# Google hosted JQuery breaks Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

My problem seems simple: When hosting my own JQuery (unedited, latest version), my Ajax calls work fine, however, when I try to replace it with the one hosted by Google or jquery.com, ajax calls do not occur upon form submission and the standard PHP version of the $_POST request occurs.

My code is the following:

```
$("#login").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#loadingGif").show();
        $("#login .formattedList").hide();

        $.post("ajax/login", {
            leftemail: $("#inp_leftemail").val(),
            leftpw: $("#inp_leftpw").val(),
            lefttoken: $("#inp_lefttoken").val(),
            remember: $("#inp_remember").is(":checked") ? "1" : false
        }, function(data) {
            $("#loadingGif").hide();
            $("#login .formattedList").show();
            if (data.success) location.reload();
            else $("#loginError").show().addClass("rounded pinkish badBorder error").html(data.msg);
            }, "json");
        });
```

Could anyone please offer some insight on what might be causing this issue?

@Steve: The code I used to include Google's JQuery is
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Tried with all `//`, `http://` and `https://` beginnings.

Comment: hard to fathom unless you are behind a firewall that prevents access to the scripts

Comment: Can you show us the `<script>` tag that you use to include the Google hosted jQuery code?

Comment: @charlietfl Shouldn't be, the reCaptcha works fine. Although perhaps being on localhost might be causing issues

Comment: @Steve: Edited my question to include the code

Comment: @Samsquanch: Firebug sat quietly

Comment: ARe you sure your latest version is THE latest version? a new one was released 1/15/2013

Comment: @KevinB I started getting this error before 1/15/2013 when it *was* the latest version, but focusing more on the application itself just rolled back to self-hosted JQuery for development. `EDIT`: It is there, the second line from the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried this: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`?

Comment: Do any errors occur? for the form to post ignoring your submit handler, a js error must be occuring, or the selector isn't finding the #login form.

Comment: @Yatrix It's a bad idea to link to the dynamic latest version, it doesn't cache very well and may result in broken production code when breaking changes occur (such as with the 1.9 update)

Comment: @Yatrix: Yes, I've tried that as well. For development I am comfortable with using my own hosted JQuery so this issue isn't a priority, however, it's curiosity that's driving me.

Comment: @KevinB as I've stated a few comments above, my Firebug console shows that the code is clean.

Comment: @Alorel that simply isn't possible though. Something is missing. Either `$("#login")` isn't targeting your form, jQuery isn't loading properly, javascript isn't running at all, or the form is being submitted by something else using `DOMNode.submit()` (which bypasses jQuery bound submit event handlers). Code doesn't just not run. 3/4 of those things can be seen from the console.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint, either in your code or in the loaded jQuery code?  Does a breakpoint in either stop the execution?

Comment: @KevinB that's what puzzles me - the code *should* run, but doesn't. I'll try and follow Chris' advice and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is the ajax call only that is failing rather than all JQuery calls?

Comment: @PerryW It isn't even getting into the submit event, otherwise it wouldn't be posting to the server due to the `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Probably me, but still unclear. So does something really basic like alert($("body *").length) work?

Comment: JQuery plugins such as tinySort work and so does everything else.

Comment: Well, if the other jQuery plugins still work when you switch the jQuery source, it can't be an issue with loading from Google. Have you set any breakpoints in your code?  Also, can you post the HTML of the form you are attaching the submit to?  Lastly, is your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(...)` (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried comparing the two as source? Put each through a JS formatter, then run a diff -- seems like there must be differences at the code level. Find those and you have a clue to pursue.

Comment: Seems like the only option I'll have one I hit production.